# Equations in "Batch normalization: theory and how to use it with Tensorflow"

Tags: mathematics, batch-normalization

I read the article [Batch normalization: theory and how to use it with Tensorflow](https://towardsdatascience.com/batch-normalization-theory-and-how-to-use-it-with-tensorflow-1892ca0173ad) by
Federico Peccia.

The batch normalized activation is
$$ \bar x_i = \frac{x_i - \mu_B}{\sqrt{\sigma_B^2 + \epsilon}} $$
where $\mu_B = \frac{1}{m} \sum_{i=1}^m x_i$ is the batch mean and $\sigma_B^2 = \frac{1}{m} \sum_{i=1}^m (x_i - \mu_B)^2$ is the batch variance.
The scaled and shifted activation is $y_i = \gamma \bar x_i + \beta$ where $\gamma$ and $\beta$ are parameters that the neural network learns.

After these definition the following set of equations appears:
[image]

I think there are mistakes in it.

Suppose there are $j$ batches, each of size $m$.
I think the first equation (inference mean) is "average of means" so it should be
$$ E_x = \frac{1}{j} \sum_{i=1}^{j} \mu_B^{(i)} $$
because this is the mean of $j$ mini-batches.

Similarly in the second equation. What are the correct formulas?

In the third equation, shouldn't it be
$$ 
y = \gamma \bar x + \beta = \gamma \frac{x - E_x}{\sqrt{\mathrm{Var}_x + \epsilon}} + \beta =
\frac{\gamma}{\sqrt{\mathrm{Var}_x + \epsilon}} x + \beta - \frac{\gamma E_x}{\sqrt{\mathrm{Var}_x + \epsilon}} ?
$$

Wikipedia ([Batch notmalization)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batch_normalization) confirms my "debugging".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the paper ["Batch Normalization: Accelerating Deep Network Training by Reducing Internal Covariate Shift"](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1502.03167.pdf) you are correct.
*m* is the batch size number and not the number of total mini-batches. So the division is by *j*. In addition, when the variables are placed in the third formula, the equation you formulate is indeed obtained.